# Connected to an Oracle Database from Oracle SQL Developer, but cannot connect from the command line

Tags: oracle

I connect successfully to an Oracle Database from Oracle SQL Developer with the following settings:

[image]

but if I connect with the same settings from the command line

```
sqlplus PDBADMIN@172.28.59.199:1521/ORCLPDB1
```

I get

```
ERROR:
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the SQLPlus documentation, to use this form of connect string on the command line, you need to enclose the whole thing in double quotes:

```
sqlplus PDBADMIN@"172.28.59.199:1521/ORCLPDB1"
```

(Depending on your OS, you may also need to escape those quotes with a backslash.)

I think syntactically this is necessary to distinguish `/servicename` from `/password`.